# Redis backplane with SignalR and AspNetBoilerPlate

Tags: asp.net-core, redis, signalr, aspnetboilerplate

I have implemented **SignalR** with **AspNetBoilerPlate** with **.Net core 3.1**. We have an azure server with multiple instances. So I am trying to implement Redis.

I followed this [link](https://codeopinion.com/practical-asp-net-core-signalr-scaling/) and installed Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.StackExchangeRedis package.

Added following code in startups ConfigureServices()

```
 services.AddSignalR().AddStackExchangeRedis("localhost:6379", options => {
            options.Configuration.ChannelPrefix = "dhub";
        });
```

I go to **cmd** and write **redis-cli** and added following command:

```
> PSUBSCRIBE d*
> PSUBSCRIBE dhub*
```

No message gets displayed when I send a message through **SendNotificationsAsync()** of **IRealTimeNotifier** of **ASPNetBoilerPlate**.

But it is not working.